# Is PowerShell 7.x now feature complete compared to PowerShell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

When PowerShell 6.x first came out, there were many gaps in what it could do compared to PowerShell 5.1, hence, anyone that works with Windows Server 2012 and 2016 in risk-aware work environments simply never touched 6.x and stuck with PowerShell 5.1 (myself included, we have no option to install PowerShell 7.x on those systems as Risk Teams jobs are to prevent all progress (*joke, but it sometimes feels that way*)).

I am curious if PowerShell 7.x would now be considered "feature complete" in that if I write a script in PowerShell 5.x, and then try to port that script to 7.x (on the same OS of course), will all of it work? And if not, what specific areas will fail and are still on the "to do list" to make 7.x feature complete with 5.1? e.g. what 5.1 cmdlets will consistently fail to work on 7.x environment, and anything else like that.

I would personally love to see a developing environment like 7.x as the standard on Windows that we can all target; 5.1 has some issues, and has been 'stagnant' for many years now, and even just things like startup times are something that I constantly struggle with as 5.1 can take 2-3 seconds for a console or any script to start (even with `-NoProfile` or ngen compilation optimisation), but I think that PowerShell 7.x is *not* default in Windows 11 (I don't have it, but googling it seems that the 'stagnant' 5.1 is still the default), so is it going to still be another 5 years until we see PowerShell 7.x as the default version on some future versions (maybe Windows 12 / Windows Server 2027)?

Comment: I think this question is too broad for the SO format. 7.x comes with many breaking changes and will propably always be like that, that's why 5.1 is still the default on Win 11. IMO it was a good decision to allow for breaking changes in newer PS versions as to not hinder progress due to compatibility burden. See [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell).

Comment: What about the 'stagnant' nature of 5.1; don't you think that is an issue? We now have a default scripting language in 5.1 that is essentially dead (no development or progress at all) as the main scripting tool on Windows. I agree with breaking changes (that's how meaningful progress happens), but the situation now leaves us with a 'stagnant' scripting environment (5.1) vs a breaking changes environment (7.x) that you *cannot rely upon being on a target system*.

Comment: Looking to all the [open feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AIssue-Enhancement), I don't think that PowerShell 7 is "feature complete".

Comment: Anyways, in our company we deal with the same situation (we are still at Windows PowerShell) but will come a time that we have to move on, therefore I have installed [PSScriptAnalyzer to check PowerShell version compatibility](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-psscriptanalyzer-to-check-powershell-version-compatibility/) in our CI/CD street as a first step to get an idea of what needs to be changed to move on.

Comment: Why does it have to be either or? We use both. Legacy scripts run on Windows PowerShell and newer ones run with PWSH. Since PS 7.x installs next to Windows PowerShell you can use both.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Microsoft have done great in making them run side by side in my opinion, but as I'm saying, if I want to write a script and send it to 30 or 40 servers, I can only rely on PowerShell 5.1 being there. So, all of the progress and developments in PowerShell 7.x are something we can't rely upon for distribution. It's depressing 5.1 is a dead/stagnant language in that respect.

Comment: @YorSubs then install PowerShell Core in all servers. It's the simplest way. Because there are so many cases there are bugs or intended different behaviors between 5.1 and 7.x, you have to target only a specific version

Comment: See above in the OP first paragraph. Many (many many many) of us do not have that option. This is the specific issue, you say "just install 7.x", but that's impossible for people working in most large corporates. If I was to say to infra teams / risk teams (in a large global corporation) "let's just install 7.x on all servers!" they would say "absolutely not, that will never happen", so we are left with a language that has been dead/stagnant for many years that will never be updated with new features.

Comment: PSCore has a compatibility pack to make it closer to WinPS. However, PSCore is an OSS project and relies on .Net Core. WIn PS (which relies on full .Net) is not. ***MS has publically stated that WinPS will be the default in the OS***, and there are no plans to remove it. By all available notices, PSCore (pwsh 6, etc.) is now and for the foreseeable future a side-by-side install.  You will see changes that say Windows Terminal will be the default shell vs cmd.exe, but things like VSCode will not be a default vs Notepad (IMO, it should be). Enterprisers not moving is a Layer 8 problem, not tech.

Comment: I don't really see it as a layer 8 problem at the corporate side, as the fact remains that it is Microsoft that is dragging their heels here; specifically, Win 11 has breaking changes in it, they've done a bunch of weird things in the OS, ***but did not make PowerShell 7.x the default scripting language.*** That's not a layer 8 problem at the corporate side, that's Microsoft holding back development. i.e. If they made PS 7.x default in Win 11, they could have ironed out any issues, and then upcoming Server OS's would also follow with PS 7.x. That's got nothing to do with the corporates, right?